# Is There a Way to Schedule URL to Content Updates?

Tags: urls, conditional-content, date-time, scheduled-posts, automation

I have a client that has multiple pages of content that will be changed on various intervals depending on the day and/or date.  For example one of the pages is "Specials of the Day"

They already know what the specials are for all seven days of the week and they simply rotate through them, after seven days it starts back at the first item.

Is there some way to have the url '/special-of-the-day' be automatically changed each night to point to the correct content that would be the specials for that day?

Comment: Are you wrong? No idea what fits your bill. Your question is very broad and arguably off-topic for that reason, but requests for plugin recommendations are definitely off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but if you want to display a special of the day, depending on the day ... I have a rough representation of how you could go about doing so.

**Example:**

```
$current_day = date('N');// 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday) - daily/weekly
//$current_day = date('j');// 1 to 31 - daily

$specials = array(
    '',
    'special 1',
    'special 2',
    'special 3',
    'special 4',
    'special 5',
    'special 6',
    'special 7',
    '23' => 'special 23',
    '24' => 'special 24',
    '25' => 'special 25'
);

if(array_key_exists($current_day, $specials) && !empty($specials[$current_day])){
    echo $specials[$current_day].PHP_EOL;
} else{
    echo 'There is no special today! :('.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$special-of-the-day is the current day
We can use like www.yoursite/com/'.$special-of-the-day.'/

We may use add_rewrite_rule
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Other wise we can use
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_day_link

Comment: Please fix your MarkUp...